# Does Howard Hinnant's date::parse() function work with floating-point durations?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, c++-chrono

I'm trying to parse `2020-03-25T08:27:12.828Z` into `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, duration<double>>` using Howard Hinnant's [Date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library.

It is expected that the following code outputs two identical strings:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace date;

int main() {
  double d = 1585124832.828;

  time_point<system_clock, duration<double>> t{duration<double>{d}}, t1;

  string s {format("%FT%TZ", t) };
  cout << s << "\n";

  stringstream ss {s};
  ss >> parse("%FT%TZ", t1);
  cout << format("%FT%TZ", t1) << "\n";

}
```

But I get:

```
2020-03-25T08:27:12.828000Z
1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
```

When I declare `t` and `t1` as follows:

```
time_point<system_clock, milliseconds> t{duration_cast<milliseconds>(duration<double>{d})}, t1;
```

the code works as expected i.e. it outputs two identical lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *can* parse floating point, but you really don't want to.  Your fix using `milliseconds` is the recommended way to go.

### Explanation:

When you format the double-based seconds, it uses `fixed` formatting which defaults to 6 decimal places.  This is why you see the 3 trailing zeroes after the `.828`.

On parse, the expected precision is driven by the precision of the input type, even if the `rep` is floating point. So with `duration<double>` it only parses the integral part of the seconds.  Then it starts looking for the trailing `Z` and finds `.` instead.  This causes the parse to fail.  If you didn't have the `Z` in the parse string, it wouldn't fail, but it also wouldn't parse the fractional part of the seconds.

If you changed the `time_point` to be double-based `microseconds`, then it works again:

```
time_point<system_clock, duration<double, micro>> t{duration<double>{d}}, t1;
```

But I consider this way too cryptic and subtle, and it still has another problem you haven't hit yet:  In C++17, `round` is supplied by the vendor as `std::chrono::round`, and this is used under the hood of `parse`.  And the C++17 version of `round` does not permit the destination `duration` to have a floating point `rep`.  So your code won't even compile in C++17 or later.

Using integral-based `milliseconds` avoids all of this complication with parsing floating point values.  And you can still convert the result back to `duration<double>` if you want to.

One subtle suggestion though:

```
time_point<system_clock, milliseconds> t{round<milliseconds>(duration<double>{d})}, t1;
```

When converting *from* floating-point based to integral-based `rep`s, I like to use `round` instead of `duration_cast`.  This avoids off-by-one errors when the underlying `double` doesn't *exactly* represent the desired value and `duration_cast` truncates in the wrong direction (towards zero).  `round` will round towards the nearest representable value.

The above can be further simplified with the `date::sys_time` templated type alias:

```
sys_time<milliseconds> t{round<milliseconds>(duration<double>{d})}, t1;
```

The above is exactly equivalent.  `sys_time<duration>` is a type alias for `time_point<system_clock, duration>`.  And in C++20, it simplifies even further with new CTAD rules:

```
sys_time t{round<milliseconds>(duration<double>{d})};
```

The `<milliseconds>` is deduced from the type of the argument (C++20).  Though you then have to declare `t1` separately, or give `t1` a `milliseconds` initial value (e.g. `, t1{0ms};`).